# How do I renegotiate my salary after I have been hired

Tags: negotiation

How do I write a renegotiation letter, after I have been hired for the job. I realize that I will be doing two full time positions not one. I was told in the interview what my position would be, also I was told that I would help out another employee with her load.

After helping out I realize that I am doing 2 full time positions, when helping my co worker, because she has a lot to do. How do I handle this matter?

Comment: How long have you been helping out this other person (how long has it been since you were hired)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a 'renegotiation letter'. You accepted a job at a compensation. If you are discontented, you can tell your manager that you are discontented. If you are valuable, your manager will negotiate. If not so much, the message will be, more or less, 'don't let the door hit you on the way through.'

If you are not paid by the hour, your job is to show up and do what needs to be done, whether it's in the form of your own unique assignment or helping someone else. If you are paid by the hour, well, more work is more hours.

Answer (score 0):

If your are paid by the hour, or your over time is paid, working more hours will automatically increase your salary. If this is not the case, you simply get paid a certain amount to do your job. Normally this would mean that your workload is such that you have to spend around 40 hours on the job. If you have to spend significantly more time than that, you have to choose if you are willing to do that (although I believe structural overtime is not effective). Your employer will however probably not compensate you for the extra time. Renegotiating your salary now will be quite hard, although you could try and make your case with your boss.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your job description - are you doing things not listed in your responsibilities and duties?

Now - everyone does do some stuff not in their job description from time to time - but if you're really taking enough load of your co-worker to be working "two full-time positions" then talk to your HR and ask them to verify what your job is; ask them to update your job description; and then ask them for a raise commensurate to your additional responsibilities.

Or, ask for another hire to take extra work.

However, it is just likely that you won't get very far with this - a lot of companies are understaffed - that's just the nature of business. If they see two people getting the work of three people done, they won't see the point in hiring another - the work is getting done. In which case, you have to demonstrate that work is not getting done - clearly showing that it is because there is more work than can be handled when you are already flat out.

Finally, if none of this results in less work load or higher pay, start looking elsewhere.